# permission denied to access localhost

Tags: localhost, apache2, permission-denied, access-denied, ubuntu-15.04

I'm using ubuntu 15.04 with apache2
I add this code below to make my web site only accessible from localhost

```
            <Directory />
                    Order deny,allow
                    Deny from all
                    Allow from localhost
                    Options -Indexes -ExecCGI
            </Directory>
```

but unfortunately this don't give me permission 
I know that the order of allow and deny is important, here I'm excpecting that apache2 deny from any host or ip and then just allow localhost, Do what I said is right or I'm misunderstanding how this works ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replacing this line `Allow from localhost` by this one `Allow from 127.0.0.1`

I hope someone explain to me why should I use the `IP` instead of `locahost`